# $.each in IE8 seems to get counted one too many times

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, each

Using $.each ...

```
  $.each(this.validationRules, function(){
        if ( !self.validateField($('#' + this.fieldID), silent) ) ...
```

Gives me an undefined error after the last element is called.. BUT ONLY IN IE8.

Does anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: I would look more at `this.validationRules` and seeing if there is a `fieldID` on the last element of it.  It could be failing on other browsers, but they just handle the error differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It common error for IE8:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,];
```

OR

```
var object = { a:1, b:2, c:3, };
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure there isn't an extra comma in your array declaration which not give the error at the last element.

Ie if the array looks like below you'll generally have problems in IE

```
validationRules = ["", "",];
```

or

```
validationRules = {"key1" : "v", "key2": "v", }
```

*note the trailing comma*